# How to change order / sequence of payment methods at checkout in Prestashop 1.7

Tags: module, prestashop, payment, checkout, prestashop-1.7

I want to change the order / sequence of payment methods at checkout in Prestashop 1.7.

My findings will be posted as an answer to this question.

I hope someone will find this helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to admin panel
2. In the left side, select IMPROVE, then DESIGN, then POSITIONS
3. Select "Payment by check" in the "Show" section
4. Select checkbox "Display non-positionable hooks"
5. A "paymentOptions" section will appear where we reposition (drag & drop) the elements as we desire.

Enjoy!